# send a text message that start specific android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**a device has an application installed which is not running. a text message sent to that device that trigger the application and start running.**

*that code is just for sending the message. what intents should be add that start some application on receiver mobile*

```
public class limitscreen extends Activity {
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.limits_set);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trig);

  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = "hello";
                String phoneNo ="5556";
                sendSMS(phoneNo,message);
            }

    });

}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, parentscreen.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
    if (sms.equals(true))
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "SMS sens", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean usual SMS? O.o Are you sure?

Comment: Well i think you need to try making a background service which listen to every sms text and a broadcast receiver to do whatever action you need once you received your text. let me know if this helped.

Comment: yes i mean usual sms._i am new on android i dont know how to make background service. can u guide me about this ?_